# Омонимичные слова

Tags: омонимы

Дали задание по мат.лингвистике - найти омонимичные слова. У меня получилось определить слово "довольно", а слова "эпиграфы" и "разбирать" преподаватель отклонил, мол, речь не идет о тонких семантических различиях и есть еще другие случаи грамматической и частеречной омонимии. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то сможет помочь! Спасибо!

Задание:

Латынь из моды вышла ныне: Так, если правду вам сказать, Он знал довольно по-латыне, Чтоб эпиграфы разбирать.

Answer (score 3):

Вышла. Здесь значение "перестать быть модным", "устареть". 2 значение - "покинуть помещение"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

1)вышла -выйти-выходить-1.уйти;2.исходить,происходить,иметь источником.Сплетня вышла из компании друзей

2)Так - вводное слово,указательное наречие(сделай так)и частица(Так вот это кто!)

3)Чтоб-союз и частица.(Чтоб тебе пусто было!)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли :)

Comment: вышла - вероятно, тоже многозначное, не омоним.

Answer (score 1):

1) довольно - в смысле много и в смысле удовлетворительном

2) разбирать - в смысле разбирать вещь или устройство, разбирать предложение или слово и еще -  понимать!

думаю, что "так" и "чтоб" не вполне подходят, а "вышла" является частью неделимого сочетания "выйти из моды"

Comment: Разбирать - не омонимы, а многозначное слово. Так и чтоб - морфологические или частеречные омонимы. Вы такие не учили? А есть ещё фонетические, омоформы, омографы.